# Cómo hacer una consulta multi tabla con inner join

Tags: php, sql

Tengo dos tablas, una se llama `laboratorio` y la otra `tbl_usuarios`, pero cuando coloco un punto (.) dentro de la variable `lab` (la que contiene el select) no he logrado mostrarlo de ninguna manera y menos sé como mostrarlo cuando son tablas combinadas y tienen campos con el mismo nombre.

```
$lab = "
     SELECT * FROM laboratorio 
    INNER JOIN tbl_usuarios 
    ON laboratorio.idmedico = tbl_usuarios.idmedico
";
$labresult = mysqli_query($conexion, $lab);
while ($ml=mysqli_fetch_assoc($labresult)) {}
```

Comment: Que error te da??

Comment: creo que deberías usar es $ml. ya que ahí se almacena mysqli_fetch_assoc($labresult). Igual explica un poco más el caso para poder ayudarte. Saludos.

Comment: ojo al detalle, SQL o MYSQL?

Answer (score 0):

Te recomendaría utilizar alias, solo por si acaso a la hora hacer un select.

El inner join parece ser correcto, la única respuesta que puedo darte de momento es:

```
SELECT * FROM laboratorio L, tbl_usuarios T where L.idmedico=T.idmedico;
```

Comment: NO ME FUNCIONA LE DIGO QUE HAGO el select uso php lo guardo en una variable pero cuando uso .... puntos.... me da error

Comment: Sería de agradecer que publicaras el error para así ver cual puede ser el fallo.

Answer (score 0):

Deberías utilizar unos alias para no confundirte y no usar el `*` para traer todo de la tabla, aun asi, no comprendo bien lo que quieres conseguir con esta consulta en php, yo te haré un ejemplo imprimiendo lo que tienes dentro de la variable.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * 
FROM laboratorio
INNER JOIN tbl_usuarios
ON laboratorio.idmedico = tbl_usuarios.idmedico";

$ejecutar = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

if ($ejecutar !== false) {
  while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($ejecutar)){
  $var = $fila['Campo de tu tabla'];
}

 } else {
  echo "Error"
}
?>
```

Aun asi, si me dices que campos quieres que aparezcan puedo mejorarte el script.

Comment: amigo lo que tengo y quiero es una tabla laboratorio que que contiene el idpaciente y idmedico entonces la tabla tbl_usuarios contiene todos los idmedico y el nombre de estos quiero con la primera tabla y el id conseguir los otros datos de los medicos que estan en tbl_usuarios

Comment: tambien el error que me pasa es que cuando uso esos puntos de donde dice laboratorio.idmedico mi editor de texto me marca error uso sublime text 3

Comment: Hola amigo, por favor, dime que campos de ambas tablas quieres imprimir y te formulo la query para que la tengas como referencia.

Comment: amigo creo que ya resolvi ese problema gracias me gustaria que me dejaras una ceunta para contactar y hablar de algunas cosas